# Non-conformable arrays in neural network - neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network

I am  trying to create a neural network using this code:

```
countries=read.table('countries.txt',header =TRUE,sep='\t',quote="",dec=",")
#install.packages("neuralnet")
library(neuralnet)

trainset<-countries[1:85,]
testset<-countries[86:118,]

retea<-neuralnet(Tari.europene~Enrolement_P+Enrolement_S, trainset, 
                 hidden=4, lifesign="minimal", linear.output=FALSE, threshold=0.1)
```

and I get this error:

> hidden: 4    thresh: 0.1    rep: 1/1    steps: Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays

Also , the results for this line are:

```
dput(trainset[c("Tari.europene", "Enrolement_P", "Enrolement_S")])
```

```
structure(list(Tari.europene = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Enrolement_P = c(195720L, 
4065L, 10172L, 4780105L, 142517L, 327246L, 103806L, 368783L, 
773568L, 51978L, 2133330L, 101667L, 1346171L, 161023L, 16630217L, 
258840L, 67023L, 2128685L, 4142775L, 2249164L, 1469099L, 4542644L, 
120381L, 13534625L, 475731L, 3176874L, 160819L, 763364L, 53129L, 
510613L, 467484L, 64319L, 7695L, 1267930L, 2093835L, 11128030L, 
777043L, 77215L, 351766L, 4188552L, 285329L, 2862690L, 4117152L, 
628753L, 13061L, 2417429L, 1150042L, 324171L, 393020L, 29892L, 
29838440L, 7441078L, 536471L, 861699L, 2862666L, 266201L, 6714539L, 
979792L, 1122282L, 8158000L, 2736224L, 114623L, 480923L, 366048L, 
683977L, 1929L, 108115L, 35435L, 3178364L, 24072L, 592249L, 105447L, 
14627368L, 138420L, 239289L, 5705343L, 5177276L, 1578L, 4401780L, 
1222867L, 360206L, 30456129L, 108254L, 425917L, 19431565L), Enrolement_S = c(333291L, 
4319L, 8077L, 4450741L, 244543L, 697388L, 90092L, 648541L, 1210112L, 
37095L, 896763L, 74227L, 1131625L, 297460L, 24224945L, 518914L, 
59823L, 2103459L, 2000076L, 2661089L, 1556372L, 4827962L, 70234L, 
4388456L, 460235L, 1418361L, 370356L, 830375L, 58634L, 781392L, 
553791L, 58553L, 5663L, 931068L, 1942230L, 8208329L, 625060L, 
77873L, 536925L, 5947212L, 281739L, 7201072L, 2265692L, 667718L, 
9736L, 1165624L, 619832L, 415971L, 857807L, 37530L, 22586955L, 
5794537L, 348116L, 767729L, 4596916L, 223920L, 7227485L, 749134L, 
1661586L, 7123778L, 3579411L, 121580L, 370359L, 130836L, 222857L, 
3387L, 277349L, 46872L, 2846473L, 30230L, 178968L, 133001L, 12993322L, 
245773L, 345223L, 1025975L, 3191268L, 1028L, 3163946L, 1573998L, 
400562L, 26894959L, 170834L, 439250L, 11286628L)), row.names = c(NA, 
85L), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't have Nan values and the columns have the same shape.

This is my data frame. Tari.europene means if the country is from Europe or not (1= European country; 0=non-European country.) The P and S from Repeaters, Enrolement and Teachers means primary and secondary cycles from system education.

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this error by introducing missing data i,e, `mtcars[1,] = NA; 
neuralnet(am~wt+mpg, mtcars, hidden=4, lifesign="minimal", linear.output=FALSE, threshold=0.1)` . Are you absolutely sure that there are no missing observations? (does `summary(trainset[c("Tari.europene", "Enrolement_P", "Enrolement_S")])` show any NA's?)

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure

Comment: okay. Can you edit your question with the results of `dput(trainset[c("Tari.europene", "Enrolement_P", "Enrolement_S")])` please -- it might be quite big.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andreea, however, if I use the data in your question the `neuralnet` function runs without error. Can you try to run this again in a fresh R session (without loading a previous workspace), using the data from your question please. (ps do you want to also add `trainset$Tari.europene = factor(trainset$Tari.europene)`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it worked in a fresh session.

Comment: Great stuff and youre welcome.